# Condense rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change the structure of a dataframe, currently it looks like this (an approximation of my data):

```
Date    Var1        Var2      Var3  Var4    Client  Code
Jan     You win!    NaN       1     NaN     Yep     100
Jan     NaN         You lose! NaN   0       Yep     100
Feb     Go for it!  NaN       1     NaN     Bar     200
Feb     NaN         Dang      NaN   0       Bar     200
Mar     Go for it!  NaN       0     NaN     Foo     300
Mar     NaN         Darn      NaN   1       Foo     300
```

Unfortunately this pattern is not consistent over the entirety of the DataFrame. Assume all the values are strings. I'm trying to condense it down based on if the Date, Client, and Code are the same.

Expected Output:

```
Date    Var1        Var2       Var3 Var4    Client  Code
Jan     You win!    You lose!  1    0       Yep     100
Feb     Go for it!  Dang       1    0       Bar     200
Mar     Go for it!  Darn       0    1       Foo     300
```

I'm really not sure how I'd do this, I guess I'm trying to group by Date, Client, and Code, but I don't want to do any aggregating I'm just trying to fill in the nans and then delete the duplicate rows.

`df` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar'],
                   'Var1': ['You win!', np.nan, 'Go for it!', np.nan, 'Go for it!', np.nan],
                   'Var2': [np.nan, 'You lose!', np.nan, 'Dang', np.nan, 'Darn'],
                   'Var3': [1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 0.0, np.nan],
                   'Var4': [np.nan, 0.0, np.nan, 0.0, np.nan, 1.0],
                   'Client': ['Yep', 'Yep', 'Bar', 'Bar', 'Foo', 'Foo'],
                   'Code': [100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html). It skips NaN values by default:

```
out = df.groupby('Date', sort=False).first().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Date        Var1       Var2  Var3  Var4 Client  Code
0  Jan    You_win!  You_lose!   1.0   0.0    Yep   100
1  Feb  Go_for_it!       Dang   1.0   0.0    Bar   200
2  Mar  Go_for_it!       Darn   0.0   1.0    Foo   300
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the NaN pattern is consistent, you can do that with the following

```
df2 = df.iloc[::2, :]
df2["Var2"] = df["Var2"][~df['Var2'].isna()].values
df2["Var4"] = df["Var4"][~df['Var4'].isna()].values

print(df2)
  Date        Var1       Var2  Var3  Var4 Client  Code
0  Jan    You win!  You lose!     1     0    Yep   100
2  Feb  Go for it!       Dang     1     0    Bar   200
4  Mar  Go for it!       Darn     0     1    Foo   300
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on my side of things: 
ValueError: Length of values (187) does not match length of index (348)
Can you tell me more about what the "~" symbol does?

Comment: It is basically a not operator. So in this case it is selecting all the values in the column that are not `Null`